# PHP Storm compile scss by Prepros

Tags: sass, phpstorm, prepros

Before i coded scss files with phpstorm 8 EAP and compile with Prepros.

In each scss files I had a green line  with "File watcher 'SCSS' is avaible for this file, .....

Now I haven"t anymore this line and Prepros don't compile. I tried to delete the SCSS file watcher but it doesn't work.

Comment: EAP stands for early access program, which essentially means beta.

Comment: Yes Ealy Access Porgram, but before posting a bug report i'd like to know if someone already had this and if he could repair it, what was his solution

Comment: Is the plugin activated? Are you able to add a new file watcher?

Comment: Yes the plugin is activated. The strange part is it worked nicely since today :( and I  changed nothing

Comment: 1) Do you actually have configured File Watcher for these files? Check in `Settings | File Watchers` -- maybe it is disabled. 2) As for actual *"green line with "File watcher 'SCSS' is avaible for this file"* prompt on the top -- you possibly have clicked on "Dismiss" button or something. If that's the case you can bring it back at `Settings | Inspections | File Watchers`